# Error in setting an associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to display the animal and the average lifespan in years, it won't show the lifepsan. Any help?

```
<?php
$animal = $_POST['animal'];

array(
$lifespans["Mouse"] => "4",
$lifespans["Queen Bee"] => "5",
$lifespans["Squirrel"] => "20",
$lifespans["Rattlesnake"] => "22",
$lifespans["Pheasant"] => "27",
$lifespans["Mallard Duck"] => "29",
$lifespans["Bear"] => "40",
$lifespans["Box Turtle"] => "123",
);

print("<p>The $animal has an average life space of $lifespans years.</p>");
```

?>

EDIT:

The user has a drop down menu of those animals and when they choose one and hit submit it will show their lifespan.

Comment: You cannot use array as string. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your array declaration makes no sense.

Comment: your array is incorrect..

Answer (score 4):

Fix your array declaration:

```
$lifespans = array(
    "Mouse" => "4", // You could also do "Mouse" => 4, etc. as PHP will type-juggle
    "Queen Bee" => "5",
    "Squirrel" => "20",
    "Rattlesnake" => "22",
    "Pheasant" => "27",
    "Mallard Duck" => "29",
    "Bear" => "40",
    "Box Turtle" => "123",
);
```

Use this to access the particular element of the array:

```
print("<p>The $animal has an average life space of $lifespans[$animal] years.</p>");
```

I'm a much bigger fan of string concatenation though:

```
print("<p>The " . $animal . " has an average life space of " . $lifespans[$animal] . " years.</p>");
```